# Redirect a user after login with ajax validation to the same page where he was

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am using this function to validate a user (ajax login) for my wordpress website.

```
 // Perform AJAX login on form submit
    $('form#vbp-login-form').on('submit', function(e){
        $('form#vbp-login-form p.status').show().text(ajax_login_object.loadingmessage);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: ajax_login_object.ajaxurl,
            data: { 
                'action': 'ajaxlogin', //calls wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin
                'username': $('form#vbp-login-form #username').val(), 
                'password': $('form#vbp-login-form #password').val(), 
                'security': $('form#vbp-login-form #security').val() },
            success: function(data){
                $('form#vbp-login-form p.status').text(data.message);
                if (data.loggedin == true){
                    document.location.href = ajax_login_object.redirecturl;

                }
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

After login the user is redirected to the home page not the page which he was on. I want the user to be redirected to the same page where he came from. How can i do this ?

Any kind help is appreciated.

Comment: I added an alternative solution in JavaScript to the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PHP SOLUTION**

I presume you are forming the `ajax_login_object` array in PHP. Probably using

```
wp_localize_script( 'your_script', 'ajax_login_object' , $ajax_login_object );
```

That is the usual WordPress method of passing data to a front end script anyway.

Try this PHP:

```
$ajax_login_object['redirecturl'] ="//".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Or try this from http://www.insertcart.com/get-current-page-url-in-wordpress/:

```
$ajax_login_object['redirecturl'] = esc_url(the_permalink());
```

Another alternative from http://mekshq.com/get-current-page-url-wordpress/ is:

```
global $wp;
$ajax_login_object['redirecturl'] = home_url(add_query_arg(array(),$wp->request));
```

**JavaScript Solution**

This is a pure JavaScript solution.

In JS `window.location.href` returns the current URL of the page. So in your code you could replace

```
document.location.href = ajax_login_object.redirecturl;
```

with

```
document.location.href = window.location.href;
```

Comment: Could you please give a little bit more info, How I can use this function in the above jquery function. Thanks James Jones

Comment: You use it on the PHP side. It isn't jQuery.

Comment: This is my php redirect function.' wp_localize_script( 'ajax-login-script', 'ajax_login_object', array( 
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'redirecturl' => home_url(),
        'loadingmessage' => __('Sending user info, please wait...')
    ));'

Comment: @LionHunter you would need to replace `home_url()` with one of the PHP lines I suggested. Or you could ignore that and use the JavaScript solution I just added.

Comment: @LionHunter No problem :), thanks for ticking the answer.

Comment: One more thing. How can i avoid the login message on the screen which remains there even after i login ? Like i try to login from the blog page. After login it still shows "you must login to comment on this post."

Comment: @LionHunter Could you please ask that as a new Stack Overflow question ? Add a link in a comment here and I may be able to answer that too.

Comment: $ajax_login_object['redirecturl'] ="//".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
this for prefectly as i need  below i post my whole function

Comment: @Naved Khan - I'm not sure what you're trying to ask me. Can you please clarify. Also I recommend not adding a comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function ajax_login_init(){
  wp_register_script('ajax-login-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/ajax-login-script.js', array('jquery'));
  wp_enqueue_script('ajax-login-script');
  $ajax_login_object  ="//".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
  wp_localize_script('ajax-login-script', 'ajax_login_object', array(
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),  
    'redirecturl' =>   $ajax_login_object, //this line for same redirect
  ));
  // Enable the user with no privileges to run ajax_login() in AJAX
  add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin', 'ajax_login');
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.